# How to implement forward-inverse-search with TeXStudio and Evince in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, texstudio, forward-inverse-search, evince

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with TexStudio and Evince 3.4.0 installed.

Can I use them to realize forward-inverse-search between my tex source code and the pdf file? How?

I tried the method described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1716268&page=2), but it doesn't work for me. Maybe this is because I don't know how to edit their code.

I tried `texstudio %f -line %l &` and `texstudio %.pdf -line %l &` in modifying the `evince` code provided in the line above.

Hopefully there will be a perfect solution.

PS: With the help of Daleif, I find out that the internal pdf-viewer of TeXStudio works perfectly on forward-inverse-search using the default `control-click` settings. I would leave this post open, in case anyone is still more interested in using the external Evince pdf reader. I will help verify the validity of solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't just use the previewer build into TeXStudio? It can be both embedded and used in a separate window.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I didn't know how to make the internal pdf viewer work while posting, and I used Sumatra with TexStudio in Windows platform. I thought I should find some way to do the forward/invert search using an external pdf viewer in Linux system. Now I think I find out how to use the internal pdf viewer properly. I just need a "control-click" to activate the forward-invert-search through the internal pdf viewer! Thank you for your reminder, and appreciate the wonderful work of the TexStudio developers!

Comment: @daleif Care to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Texmaker comes with a build in PDF previewer that supports synctex. If I remember correctly, it is "embedded" by default. That is, editor and previewer is a part of the same bigger window. This might not be useful if the screen is small, say on a small laptop. Editor and previewer can be separated into two separate Windows via the Texmaker configuration (just remove the tick mark at "embedded" and restart Texmaker)

Texmakers cousin Texstudio made this even easier: there the separation is a button on the previewer.